# CKEditor gui appears grayed out/disabled

Tags: ckeditor

I'm attempting to set up a CKEditor 4 instance inside a form.  The editor gui loads, but appears to be disabled.  None of the buttons are clickable, nor can I type in the text box.

[image]

Code:

```
<script src='/js/ckeditor4/ckeditor.js'></script>

<div class='field'>
  <label class='label'>Page Content</label>
  <div class='control'>

    <textarea rows='20' class='textarea' name='p_page_html' id='form_page_edit'>$page_html</textarea>
  </div>
 </div>

<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="form_page_edit"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'form_page_edit' );
</script>
```

Here's my instance of CKEditor's [config.js](https://pastebin.com/0mu1QZu9).

There are zero errors when viewing the console.

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Is the `form_page_edit` textarea disabled?

Comment: The `form_page_edit` textarea is not disabled or read only.

Comment: Please try with a CDN version instead of your own hosted one.